# Why do built-in functions not have a prototype property?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Given that the ES 5.1 standard states that...

1) Note at the foot of http://es5.github.com/#x13.2

```
NOTE A prototype property is automatically created for every function,
to allow for the possibility that the function will be used as a constructor.
```

2) http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.5.2

```
NOTE Function objects created using Function.prototype.bind do not have
a prototype property.
```

(which implies that all other functions do)

...why do built-in functions no longer have a prototype property?:

```
[].push.prototype; //undefined
Math.max.prototype; //undefined
```

Moreover these built-ins cannot be used as constructors even when they are assigned a prototype property:

```
[].push.prototype = {};
[].push.prototype; //[object Object]
new [].push(); //TypeError: function push() { [native code] } is not a constructor
```

Conversely, removing the prototype property from a user defined object still allows it to be used as a constructor, and in fact assigns a generic object to the [[prototype]] of the generated instances:

```
var A = function() {};
A.prototype = undefined;
A.prototype; //undefined
(new A()).__proto__; //[object Object]
```

Are built in functions now sub-typed as either constructors or functions?

[Tested in most modern browsers]

Comment: It might be because they are implemented in non-javascript code, and thus might not have a `prototype`.  This is pure speculation.

Comment: "Moreover these built-ins cannot be used as constructors even when they are assigned a prototype property:" -- now this line got me interested

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee great idea; however, I don't see a reason why native functions couldn't be constructors. After all, `new console.log` (native in Chrome) throws `illegal invocation`, not `not a constructor`. Also, `Array` is native (in chrome), but it _can_ be called as a constructor (quite easily).

Comment: It's probably because they don't want the built-in functions to be tampered with.  There are more than likely possible security risks.

Comment: "not a constructor" is normally thrown when the attempted constructor is not a function (but `[].push` is).

Comment: @AlexW I can't think of any. All that constructors do is to 1) create an object, 2) assign its prototype, 3) call the function on the new object, 4) return the new object. These functions are not bound either.

Comment: It seems that browser funcions in Chrome consistently throw "illegal invocation", while ecmascript functions consistently throw "not a constructor". Even stranger, `new navigator` throws "not a function", not "not a constructor".

Comment: @JanDvorak There might be the creation a native object which is wrapped with javascript. (as opposed to native functions which perform a specific task)

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee new always returns an object, never a primitive value; `new function(){return 1}` returns `{}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not the `.prototype` that allows a function to be used as a constructor, but the presence of the [`[[Construct]]`](http://es5.github.com/#x13.2.2) internal method. See [this section](http://es5.github.com/#x11.2.2), step 4.

Normal functions created by the user script automatically have this internal property set, so all user functions can be called as constructors. This is because the interpreter can't know how the user intends to use that method.

For native functions the intended usage is known in advance, so the javascript engine can decide which native functions should be callable as constructors. Does it make sense to invoke `new [].push`?

It is mentioned in the [introductory part to built-in objects](http://es5.github.com/#x15) that:

> None of the built-in functions described in this clause that are not constructors shall implement the [[Construct]] internal method unless otherwise specified in the description of a particular function. None of the built-in functions described in this clause shall have a prototype property unless otherwise specified in the description of a particular function.

And the reason, IMHO, is that there is no valid real use case that would need that. There's no good explanation why `push` should be instantiable: what's the difference between a new `push` and a new generic object? So, allowing the instantiation of those functions doesn't bring any value to the developer, but it will raise lots of [WTFs](http://www.osnews.com/images/comics/wtfm.jpg) from others reading the code.

Comment: " Does it make sense to invoke new `[].push`?" -- my question is - Is there a reason to prevent it? _Why_ don't they have the `[[Construct]]` set?

Comment: Yes, less WTFs. What would an instance of `push` do?

Comment: It would be the same as `var o={}; [].push.call(o); return o`.

Comment: Just a note: The ability to make functions unconstructable will be available to a degree in ES6 through Proxies, which can distinguish between the construct and call operations. In addition, the ability to directly modify the construct and call operations on user functions has been discussed as a possibility for ES7: https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2012-October/025465.html -- Meaning this may no longer just be magic that only ES built-ins can do.