# Can't replicate inbuilt function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, dom, replication, built-in

[Why do built-in functions not have a prototype property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169384/why-do-built-in-functions-not-have-a-prototype-property)
I see a post on the above link but it is not solving my problem.
**I am able to replicate some built in objects like**

```js
var w=window;
w.alert("hi");
var d=document;
console.log(d.getElementById);
```

**But I can't replicate functions**

```js
var a=document.getElementById;
console.log(a);
```

**The prototype gets copied but when invocating It is not working**

```js
var a=document.getElementById;
console.log(a('id'));
```

**I use this to lower the coding effort. I know that I can achieve this by using**

```js
function a(id){
 return document.getElementById(id);
}
console.log(a('id'));
```

But this is not what I am looking for. Is there any other way to replicate a funciton

Comment: `var a = document.getElementById.bind(document);` works.

Comment: It's nothing to do with the prototype, but *this* when *getElementById* is called must be set to *document*. In the 3rd example you could also do `a.call(document, id)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Xufox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4642212/xufox) , This is working. Thanks a lot

```js
var a = document.getElementById.bind(document);
console.log(a('id'));
```